# How to use the function R sweep

Tags: r

How to use the function R `sweep`

In R, I want to use the function `sweep`.

I don't want to scale using `mean` and `sd`, but `min` and `max`.

I want to calculate  this `yi = (xi - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))` in a matrix.

I don't know how to do ... thank you for your answer

Comment: The function is well documented. Type `?sweep` in your console! If you have a certain use case, then show a minimal reproducible example!

Answer (score 3):

Ways to go about this:

##### 1:

```
dat <- data.matrix(iris)
apply(dat, 2, \(x)(x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
```

##### 2:

```
r <- matrixStats::colRanges(dat)
scale(dat, r[,1], diff(t(r))
```

##### 3:

```
sapply(data.frame(dat), scales::rescale)
```

I highly doubt `sweep` can be used for this particular problem

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `apply`, e.g. here is how to use your scaling on each column of a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(runif(25), nc = 5)

my_scale <- function(v) (v - min(v)) / (max(v) - min(v))
m_scaled <- apply(m, 2, FUN = my_scale)
```

Comment: Thank you, that’s exactly what I wanted to do.
I am a beginner on R and I was looking for the way to perform the same operation in parallel on all rows/ all columns of a matrix.